# CSS Float In Internet Explorer

Tags: css

I'm currently designing a [simple blog theme](http://zulhilmizainudin.com/live/). But, I have a problem. The 'post_meta' section where the post date, author name & category name placed (wrapped in a class which I make it float) does not float well in Internet Explorer like in Firefox and Google Chrome browser does.

The main point here is, I just want to make the 'post_meta' section placed right in the center of the page. That's all.
Hope you guys can help me.

Thank you!

Comment: show us some code that you've tried. It's hard to guess what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: This webpage is not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method:

1. remove the empty div with class col1.
2. Don't float col2 div to the left, instead use `margin:0 auto;`, this will center it on the screen:

   ```
   .col2{
      background:;
      height:30px;
      width:350px;
      margin: 0 auto;
     }
   ```

Comment: also `<div class="col3"></div>` doesn't make sense.